# quiz file using header file not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

This is the header file i am using to access the quiz question bank, the question file and this header works but the next section of code were i generate a random question and add a timing element doesnt work and i was wondering why.

```
            #ifndef Question_h // defines question
            #define Question_h // question bank
            #include <iostream> //include iostream
            #include <string> //includes a string
            #include <fstream> 


            using namespace std;
            ofstream file;
            class Question
            {
            private:
```

the quiz consists of questions with 200characters
4answers and a integer as the correct answer

```
                char question_text[200];
                char answers_text[4][200];
                int correct_answer;


            public:
```

assessor variables used to get the qustions from question bank

```
                std::string GetQuestionText();
                void SetQuestionText();
```

string to get the correct answer

```
                std::string GetAnswerText(int answer);
                void SetAnswerText();
```

the answer number

```
                int GetCorrectAnswerNo();
                void SetCorrectAnswerNo();


                void SetQuestion(); //nothing returned, and no arguements.


                void createandwritefile();


                char text[201];
                char answerYN;
                int number;


            };




            #endif

            // This is my code which doesnt seem to be working properly 
// should generate random questions and times the person so they only have 15sec

            #include <string> //Adds the string to the code
            #include <iostream> //This is the input and output of the code 
            #include <ctime> //This is the timing element of the code 
            #include <fstream>
            #include "Question.h" /** Access to Leanne's Question Bank 

            }
            int main ( )
            {

            // to randomly generate the quiz questions
            class Randomly generate data
                int q_no;
                int reply;
                int i=0;
                bool already-used=FALSE;
                int q_list[10];

                unsigned seed=time(NULL);
    // Generates a number between 1 and 30
                // with max number 30
//min number 1
//using a pseudo ranom function

                        srand(seed)
                    int min=1;
                    int max=30;
                    int range=max-min+1
                    q_no=rand()/100%range+min
            q_list[0]=rand()/100%range+min;
                    while(i++<10)

                    {
                        do

                        {
                            already_used =FALSE; // if number is already used it generates another random number
                            q_list[i]=rand()/100%range+min;
                            for(int j=0; j<i; j++)

                            {
                                if (q_list[j]==q_list[i])
                                    already_used=TRUE;
                            }
                        }

                        while (already_used==TRUE);
    //if the same number has been used before the loop begins again

                    }

    //gets the questions from the question bank
    //the question comes with 4answers

                cout<<QuestionBank[q_no-1].GetQuestionText();
                cout<<QuestionBank[q_no-1].GetANswerText(0);
                cout<<QuestionBank[q_no-1].GetANswerText(1);
                cout<<QuestionBank[q_no-1].GetANswerText(2);
                cout<<QuestionBank[q_no-1].GetANswerText(3);

                    cin>>reply
                        if (reply==QuestionBank[q_no-1}.GetCorrectAnswerNo());
                    cout<<"Well Done Thats the Right Answer";
                        else
                    cout<<"Not So Smart This Time";

    //if the answer is the right reply the user gets told if not get informed they arent so smart



            class TimingElement

    //determines if the player completes the question within 15seconds if not time is up

            {   // Start time is recorded and the user is given 15sec

                    time_t start = time(NULL);

                    cin >> user_input;

                    delay = time(NULL)-start;

                    if(delay > 15)


                    {
                         cout <<"\n\n\t\t\tYou Took too long this time!! (" << delay << " seconds.)";

                         return(0);

                    }
            If they answer within 15seconds
                    if(operatorA == user_input)


                    {
                         cout<<"\n\n\t\t\tCorrect";
                         return(1);


                    }
```

when answered correct within the time given

```
                    else


                    {

                           cout <<"\n\n\t\t\tNot so smart this time  ";
                           return(0);
```

if not answered within the given time
                        }

```
            }

             return(0);
```

end of the code

Comment: Exactly what is your error?

Comment: Are you trying to place everything in the header file?

Comment: Can I recommend you clean up your code a bit to make it more readable? It's a real benefit that will pay dividends down the road, especially when you come back in 3 months and are trying to decipher what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TimingElement` class definition is incorrect.

Have a read through this [class tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) to understand how to define and use classes in c++.